# Can you create a table of hyperlinks within a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

Is it possible in MS Word (2010) to create a table of Hyperlinks?

I have a document that uses many, but it's a large document, so I'm looking for a way to allow users to find them quickly and easily.

The table of contents and the table of figures sadly don't look like what I need, but please correct me if I am wrong. Thans.